# Does day-usage of bed set respawn location anyway?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to set a new respawn location, but it is currently day time and I "can only sleep at night", therefore I cannot sleep in my bed. Does trying to use a bed and getting this message set one's respawn location regardless of not actually sleeping, or must I sleep to set my respawn location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Daytime bed use during rain]I’m not going to go jump off a cliff to test it, but it appears in September, 2021 Bedrock Edition that you can. No “sleeping” occurred, but respawn point says set.

Answer (score 4):

No, according to the wiki, you need to actually sleep in the bed for you spawn to change :

> Sleeping on the bed changes your spawn point to the bed.

same result on gamepedia

> Once the player has entered the bed, the spawn point is set near the bed.

and fun fact I didn't know, you can actually use the bed during daytime :

> At daytime, they can also be used during thunderstorms.

Sources :

- http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Bed
- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed

Comment: I just tested (on 1.8). The answer to my question is "no".

Comment: I forgot to put the "no" in my answer ^^

Comment: This answer is only valid for Minecraft 1.14 or older, they changed that behavior in 1.15: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Bed#History